# Embedded Google maps opening app on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I have a google map embedded in a Bootstrap site. I am busy testing on different mobile devices and when I am on iOS and I open the page with the embedded map on it, the maps app on the device is opened.

I don't think I am doing anything fancy, but I would just like it to stop. This does not occur on Android devices.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<section>
    <div class="well well-sm">
        <iframe width="100%" height="350" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=central%2Bpark&ie=UTF8&z=12&t=m&iwloc=near&output=embed"></iframe>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behavior of iphone/ipad with regard to maps. To change the behavior follow these steps as stated in [Google Support](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3006766?hl=en) :

1.Visit the Search Settings page from your iPhone or iPad.

2.Scroll down to the "Google Maps" section.

3.Select Never use the native app.

4.Touch Save at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Is there no way, programmatically, to keep this from happening? (Other than serving a static google maps image)